# The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Error message

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         t.[Statement_ID], t.[InvoiceID], 
         t.S_Type as Type, t.Description, t.Date, 
         t.Debit, t.Credit, b.Balance 
     FROM 
         Statement as t 
     CROSS apply 
         (SELECT Balance = SUM(Debit) - SUM(Credit) 
          FROM Statement as x 
          WHERE (x.date < t.date or x.date = t.date and x.[Statement_ID] <= t.[Statement_ID] ) 
            AND x.CustID = t.CustID ) b 
     WHERE  
          t.CustID = '48' 
          AND date between '2015-01-01' AND '2016-01-01' 
     ORDER BY
         t.date) 
ORDER BY
    InvoiceID, Statement_ID
```

Comment: And what is the problem? The error message says exactly what is wrong.

Comment: remove `order by t.date` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx

Comment: i get the same error

Comment: use TOP 100 PERCENT in your inline query

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen - Whilst that may shut up the compiler, it doesn't achieve anything useful, except possibly causing the server to waste some resources

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever but it would still shut up the compiler ;)

Comment: I think dasblinkenlight's answer was mostly correct, had they not chosen to use `inner`, a keyword, as the alias.

Comment: Especially in SQL Server, [don't use `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Use an exclusive upper-bound (`<`) instead.  For instance, I find a range that is "a month and a day" to be unusual (usually you only want **1 month**).

Comment: Also `AND date between '2015-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'` I think it is more precise like `AND ( (  '2015-01-01' <= date ) and ( date < '2016-01-01') )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move first ORDER BY  to the end:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         t.[Statement_ID], t.[InvoiceID], 
         t.S_Type as Type, t.Description, t.Date, 
         t.Debit, t.Credit, b.Balance 
     FROM 
         Statement as t 
     CROSS apply 
         (SELECT Balance = SUM(Debit) - SUM(Credit) 
          FROM Statement as x 
          WHERE (x.date < t.date or x.date = t.date and x.[Statement_ID] <= t.[Statement_ID] ) 
            AND x.CustID = t.CustID ) b 
     WHERE  
          t.CustID = '48' 
          AND date >= '2015-01-01' AND date <= '2016-01-01' 
         ) x
ORDER BY
    Date, InvoiceID, Statement_ID
```

Comment: You need an alias for a subquery in `FROM`. This will currently error with "incorrect syntax near `ORDER BY`..." or words to that effect. `t` would be a suitable one and would make the reference to `t` in the `ORDER BY` valid again also (there's no `t` alias visible in the outer query, currently).

Comment: Cough. You've made half of the correction I suggested. Re-read the third sentence in the previous comment. `t.date` is still going to cause issues as this currently stands.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't realised that it is refering to alias, which obviously won't be valid in outer query. Now the ORDER BY is using the column name, so will work fine. I have also changed the BETWEEN to >= AND <= (Please read: https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common )

Comment: Also if Date is in Datetime format, please explicitly convert or cast this to DATE datatype

Comment: thanks Petrik for the solution