# Entity Framework Core; using ORDER BY in query against a (MS) SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-order-by, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use the following query in combination with Entity Framework Core against a Microsoft SQL Server 2016:

```
SELECT [a], [b], [c]
FROM [x]
WHERE [a] = {0}
ORDER BY  [b]
```

I use this query like so:

```
context.MySet.AsNoTracking()
  .FromSql(MyQuery, aValue)
  .Skip(pageSize * page)
  .Take(pageSize)
  .Select(x => x.ToJsonDictionary())
  .ToList()
```

I use this in a .NET Core REST API with pagination and I'd like to have the records sorted (alphabetically) to make the pagination more usable.
I get the following error when executing the above statement:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET
>   or FOR XML is also specified.Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the
>   FETCH statement. The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline
>   functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions,
>   unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.Invalid usage of the
>   option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

Looking for similar issues I found these some other posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18031421/6459948), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18085990/6459948), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34653832/6459948)) but none of which where used in combination with EF Core and/or they were using it in a different context which does not apply in my case (e.g. subquery).

I tried to use the `.OrderBy(..)` syntax of EF instead of in the `ORDER BY` in the query but this doesn't solve the problem. I also tried adding `TOP 100 PERCENT` after the `SELECT` in the query in combination with the `ORDRE BY`; this worked but didn't order the column. It just got ignored. This limitation is described under the [EF Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql). I also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1623240/6459948) that replace the `TOP 100 PERCENT...` with `TOP 99.99 PERCENT...` or `TOP 9999999...` `. This seems like it should work but it doesn't 'feel' right.
This issue in general is further explained [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/23/sql-server-order-by-does-not-work-limitation-of-the-views-part-1/).

> Summary: It is not advisable to use ORDER BY in Views. Use ORDER BY
>   outside the views. In fact, the correct design will imply the same. If
>   you use TOP along with Views, there is a good chance that View will
>   not return all the rows of the table or will ignore ORDER BY
>   completely.

Further I'm confused by the word "view". For me, the term views refers to the usage of the ones created by the `CREATE VIEW ..` syntax. Is a plain, 'normal' SQL query also considered a view? Or is EF Core wrapping the request in some sort of view and this is the real issue causing this error?

I'm not sure, but so far all the 'solutions' I found seem kind of 'hacky'. 
Thoughts?

Comment: `MyQuery` is just raw sql that contains the ORDER BY clause? Sounds like you need to take out the ordering in that.

Comment: A good debugging tool: take off `ToList()` and make the rest equal to some variable. Inspect the value of that variable after it executes but before you "evaluate it" with `ToList()`. That should give you the generated sql. If you see an `order by` inside a view or CTE, you're going to have that error.

Comment: @gunr2171 MyQuery is the query from above and serves as an example. The real query consists of a few join and more..

Comment: @gunr2171 right, thank you for the tip. and yes, there needs to be an order by, that is the goal. I'm trying to find a solution to make this work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's simplify things a bit. Here's what I came up for testing. I've also added [some code for printing the generated sql from EF queries](https://gist.github.com/rionmonster/2c59f449e67edf8cd6164e9fe66c545a#gistcomment-2288137).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DbClient context = new DbClient();

        var rawSql = "select [Id], [Title] from Post order by [Title]";

        var query = context.Posts.AsNoTracking()
            .FromSql(rawSql)
            .Skip(1)
            .Take(4)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Title);

        var generated = query.ToSql();

        var results = query.ToList();
    }
}

class DbClient : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("conn_string");
    }
}

class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{Id} | {Title}";
}
```

When we look at the value of `generated` we see what the sql of the `query` is:

```
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[Title]
FROM (
    SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[Title]
    FROM (
        select [Id], [Title] from Post order by [Title]
    ) AS [p]
    ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
    OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY
) AS [t]
ORDER BY [t].[Title]
```

Notice that there three `order by` clauses, the inner-most one is the one from `rawSql`.

We can look at the error message to see why it's not legal:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in [...] subqueries [...] unless OFFSET [...] is also specified.

The middle order by *does* include offset, so that's valid even though it's inside a subquery.

To fix this, just simply remove the ordering from your `rawSql` and keep using the `OrderBy()` linq method.

```
var rawSql = "select [Id], [Title] from Post";

var query = context.Posts.AsNoTracking()
    .FromSql(rawSql)
    .Skip(1)
    .Take(4)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Title);
```

This generates:

```
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[Title]
FROM (
    SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[Title]
    FROM (
        select [Id], [Title] from Post
    ) AS [p]
    ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
    OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY
) AS [t]
ORDER BY [t].[Title]
```

Now, all order by clauses are either not in subqueries, or have an offset clause.

Comment: this is a fantastic answer, thank you. the Problem is only that I want to order it first before skipping and taking, because I'd like the whole result set ro basically seem sorted

Comment: imagine this: xzy-acb-oqp vs. xyz-abc-opq vs. abc-opq-xyz

Comment: Simply reorder the linq methods: .FromSql(rawSql)
                .OrderBy(x => x.Title)
                .Skip(1)
                .Take(4);

Comment: I tried this already, yet without success. I still get the same exception. But I get a good idea on how to solve the issue. I could, in theory, just add an `OFFSET 0` to my inner query, couldn't I? This would fulfil the requirements for a subquery. Also, do you know why dis limitation exists? I don't see why I shouldn't be able to order a result without declaring an offset for it

Comment: I tested it again and you're right. The `OrderBy(..)` does work; tbh I don't know why it didn't during my test phase, maybe I forgot to reset something. Anyhow, I also tested my assumption about `OFFSET 0 ROWS` - it works. This means that there are two good solutions to this problems, the first being the `OrderBy(..)` and the second one to use `ORDER BY [x] OFFSET 0 ROWS`. I'll extend your answer and accept it